# How openshift - postgresql load data from local file?

Tags: postgresql, openshift

I created app on openshift and added a cartridge postgresql.
There is no manage application like pgadmin supported by openshift.
I manage the DB by PuTTY under windows.
But how I can import the local data to the DB on openshift.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

First take backup of your database using below command.

> pg_dump dbname > outfile

Then

add the `postgresql` database like so

```
rhc-ctl-app –a postgresApp –e add-postgresql-8.4
```

then access the remote psql and you can `restore` using this command  `pg_restore`